# Fill Dataframe column with list that repeats for each item in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists of numbers that I want to use for a calculation, but they are not the same length.

list_1 = [123, 456, 789, 987]

list_2 = [321, 654]

Since there are 4x2 = 8 total combinations, I want to have them output like so:

```
       Calc_1                    Calc_2
Calc_of_list_1_num_1      Calc_of_list_2_num_1
Calc_of_list_1_num_2      Calc_of_list_2_num_1
Calc_of_list_1_num_3      Calc_of_list_2_num_1
Calc_of_list_1_num_4      Calc_of_list_2_num_1
Calc_of_list_1_num_1      Calc_of_list_2_num_2
Calc_of_list_1_num_2      Calc_of_list_2_num_2
Calc_of_list_1_num_3      Calc_of_list_2_num_2
Calc_of_list_1_num_4      Calc_of_list_2_num_2
```

I've been struggling with this and I'm just not sure how to approach it.

Comment: should `Calc_2` stay in ascending/sorted order even if the `list_2` would be `list_2 = [321, 654, 212]` ?

Comment: Yes, it should be ascending.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy's [np.ufunc.outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html):

Example Addition:

```
np.add.outer(list_1,list_2)
```

output:

```
array([[ 444,  777],
       [ 777, 1110],
       [1110, 1443],
       [1308, 1641]])
```

To create dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.add.outer(list_1,list_2), columns=list_2, index=list_1)
```

Output:

```
      321   654
123   444   777
456   777  1110
789  1110  1443
987  1308  1641
```

For multiplication use np.outer:

```
np.outer(list_1,list_2)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 39483,  80442],
       [146376, 298224],
       [253269, 516006],
       [316827, 645498]])
```

And for dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.outer(list_1,list_2), columns=list_2, index=list_1)
```

Output:

```
        321     654
123   39483   80442
456  146376  298224
789  253269  516006
987  316827  645498
```

Comment: How would you suggest implementing a way to only multiply if they meet another criteria?  Specifically if both numbers are within 100-199, 200-299, etc.?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Could you go a head calculate and filter your dataframe afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult for me to articulate.

So I have the lists:

list_1 = [123, 456, 789, 987]

list_2 = [321, 654]

I want to run one calculation if they're not in the same range (i.e. 100-199)

list_1 * 100

if they are in the same range, I want to do:

list_1 * 100 + 5